# SharePoint Search Result PNP Question

Tags: sharepoint-online, kql

Good Day!

I have run into an issue with my Search Result WebPart. The desired outcome for this is to look into 3 different folders and give back a scrolling output of the newest files within these 3 folders, all of which are in different areas of the document library. I have tried to use the Query Editor on the webpart to make everything talk, but i am new to it and i think i am missing something. Could i get some help on this? This is what i have at current time:

[image: QueryExample]

The following would be one of the filepaths IN sharepoint for where im trying to get the webpart to look:
[image: FilePath]

If any more detail is needed just let me know! Thank you all in advance!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-settings-for-the-search-results-web-part-40ff85b3-bc5e-4230-b1dd-f088188e487e

To change the query in the Search Results Web Part:

- Go to Settings -> Edit Page.
- In the Search Results Web Part, to the right of the Web Part title, click the arrow then click Edit Web Part on the menu.
- In the Web Part tool pane, click Change query.
- Define your KQL query: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/configure-properties-of-the-search-results-web-part

See the resources, try this and let me know if this helps.